# Livewire uncaught (in promise) DOMException with select

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a dropdown in my component that seems to be causing an error in Livewire.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute'
> on 'Element': '?' is not a valid attribute name.

I added the `wire:key` code based on what I read in the docs under the troubleshooting section, but it didn't seem to help. It updates the value on save just like it should, but when it refreshes the dom with the new data, it's not working.

Here's the offending element:

```html
<div class="mb-3 col-md-4 ">
    <label for="state" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select wire:model.defer="location.state" class="form-select" 
        id="state" name="state">
        @foreach ($states as $state)
            <option 
                name="{{ $state->name }}" 
                id="{{ $state->code }}" 
                wire:key="{{ $state->id }}"
                value="{{ $state->code }}"
                @if (isset($location->state) 
                    && $location->state === $state->code) ? selected @endif
            >{{ $state->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here,

```
@if (isset($location->state) && $location->state === $state->code) 
    ? selected 
@endif
```

Where it tries to apply `?` as an attribute on the element, but `?` is not a valid attribute. Just remove the `?`.

---

That said, you cannot use the `selected` property on `<select>` elements in Livewire to set the selected value. You need to set the value of your `wire:model` in your component. This means that you have to **remove the `@if(..) selected @endif`** from your Blade entirely, and instead set the value in your component,

```
public function mount() {
    $this->location['state'] = $state->code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same error - on my part it was solved by calling the livewire component in a authenticated context- it was failing because it was calling login (as a result of being called from a guest context)

If it doesn't work for you please ignore but it sorted me out.